# How to create a value: index dict from a python list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, enumerate

I have a list:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to get the dict:

```
b = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
```

What is the most pythonic way to get that?

Comment: What have you tried? We can then tell you whether it is Pythonic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the following help you?

```
b = dict(map(lambda t: (t[1], t[0]), enumerate(a)))
```

Example:

```
>>> dict(map(lambda t: (t[1], t[0]), enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])))
{'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'a': 0}
```

Comment: is your answer faster or the one from Dark?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest (and imo most pythonic) way of doing this would be:

```
b = dict(enumerate(a))
```

Comment: You have to swap key and values.

Comment: In your question the target dictionary has the numbers as keys.

Comment: Oh you are right. The title is correct but I wrote it wrong in the question body. sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = dict(enumerate(a))
print(b)
```

It will produce:

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Comment: You have to swap key and values.

Answer (score 0):

use `index`:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dict_a = {}
for x in a:
    dict_a[a.index(x)] = x
print(dict_a)
```